# Gaussian Random Process with Unit Mean

Tags: matlab, random, gaussian

I want to generate a Gaussian Random Process with Unit `Mean(mean=1)` in `MATLAB`. I tried to do randn function but I later learned that it can be only used when mean is `0` so I tried to write the process by hand. I wanted to write the Gaussian function with `mean = 1` and `var = 1`. I tried this code:

```
N = rand(1000,1);
g1 = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((N-1).^2)/2);
plot(g1)
m = mean(g1)
v = var(g1)
```

However, when I check the mean and variance values I get `m=0.3406` and `v=0.0024`. Can you help?

Comment: `N` is a vector of samples of a Gaussian process. `g1` is the (first-order) density function. I think you are mistaking those two things. Besides, I don't see why you apply the density function to the samples. Do you simply want to generate the samples `N` with unit mean? In that case, just use `N = 1 + rand(1000,1);`

Comment: Is it correct if I use the Gaussian function instead of randn function or should I try something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `randn`,  not `rand`, in my previous comment. If you try `N = 1 + randn(1000,1);` and check  `mean(N), var(N)` you will see they are very close to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the vector from randn() and then add one it will have the same standard deviation as before but now it'll also have a mean of 1.

v=randn(1000,1)+1

Comment: A small tip, you can use code highlighting in your answer. This is achieved using four spaces in front of `v=randn(1000,1)+1` and apostrophes (or whatever that symbol is called) around in-line code as shown in the help.